# Electron app while opening shows Black screen first

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

When we first start electron browse window it shows black colour display. Also when we use property window.maximize() it shows solid black border around window. I also tried with different versions like 21.2.3 and 22.0.0 but it shows same. Currently I am using windows 10 version.

I am trying with different windows versions like window 11 and also tried with electron 22.0.0 but its shows same

Comment: yeah it happens. but doesnt matter when afterwards it shows the correct content

Comment: Yes it doesn’t matter but any solution on this

Comment: Not that i am aware of. Seems to be a bit random aswell. for example i never had this for weeks while colleques had the black screen already before. then suddenly I got it too. I think it has something to do with antivirus software.